# Can we sort answers in android app?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

There should be sorting features (same as web) while viewing answers. Its required when question is having more answers.

I am talking about sorting features same as on web:

1. active
2. oldest
3. votes

> [image]

Comment: Sorting by votes is useful for main sites, where there are relatively few answers per question and the best answers rise to the top.  It's pretty useless for *following discussions on meta* questions with lots of answers; I don't want to scroll past twenty answers I've read to see the most recently posted/edited answer.  Following the licensing brouhaha from my phone was basically impossible.